# Kernels of linear transformations and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be vector spaces. Let $P,Q: A \rightarrow A$ be a linear transformation and $R: A \rightarrow B$ be an isomorphism. Can we say,
$$
ker(RQR) = ker(RPR) \implies ker(Q)=ker(P)
$$

Comment: Yes, your statement is correct

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the implication is false? How?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my comment

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is there a proof for it?

Comment: Yes: it suffices to note that $x \in \ker(Q) \iff R^{-1}x \in \ker(RQR)$.